# What abilities should I concentrate on while bug hunting, and how can I improve the quality of my bug bounty reports?

Tags: security, owasp, nist

I have encountered a situation where my bug reports submitted to a bug bounty program have been consistently rejected without clear explanations. To increase the likelihood of success and improve the quality of my submissions, I'm seeking advice on how to enhance the effectiveness and thoroughness of my bug reports. What strategies or approaches can I adopt to ensure that my bug reports meet the program's standards and increase my chances of receiving rewards?

I am expecting to get guidance in field of cybersecurity and bug hunting and to learn more about the field.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a tutoring, mentoring or guidance site. Please review the [ask] and [tour] links. For finer grade details on how to use the site, please check out the [help] links.